# How to print the value of a velocity variable into a hidden HTML input

Tags: html, velocity

During my searching, I would like to have a tip on this :

How to pass the value :

```
${lyear}-${key}
```

to the value input type below :

```
<input type="hidden" name="month2" value="" />
```

For instance :

```
<input type="hidden" name="month2" value=#set(${lyear}-${key}) />
```

I tried this, but It doesn't work !

If you have a advice to give me.

So I worked and :

```
<input type="hidden" name="month2" value=${lyear}-${displayMonth} />
```

And :

```
<input type="hidden" name="month2" value="${lyear}-${displayMonth}" />
```

To have a query in a the navigator like that :

> localhost:8080/comptes/mon_compte.html?display=affilies_periode&month1=01&year=2013&month2=%24***{lyear}**-**Décembre***

But I would like to have a query looks like :

> localhost:8080/backoffice/vendeurs/remuneration.html?month=2013-08

Thanks for any comments

P.S. The code of my form :

```
#set ( $listKeys = [ '01' , '02' , '03' , '04' , '05' , '06' , '07' , '08' , '09' , '10' , '11' , '12' ] )

#set ( $listMois = { '01' : "Janvier" , '02' : "Février" , '03' : "Mars" , '04' : "Avril" , '05' : "Mai" , '06' : "Juin" , '07' : "Juillet" , '08' : "Août" , '09' : "Septembre" , '10' : "Octobre" , '11' : "Novembre" , '12' : "Décembreuujikjk" } )


                <fieldset class="search">


                   <form method="get" action="/comptes/mon_compte.html" style="border-top:none;"><p class="alignTop">

                   <p>

                        <span>Afficher vos détails de rémunération du mois de </span>

                        <input type="hidden" name="display" value="affilies_periode" />

                        <select name="month1" id="month1">
                            #foreach($key in $listKeys)
                                #if($listMois.get($key))
                                    #set ($displayMonth = $listMois.get($key))
                                    <option value="$key" #if($month == $key) selected #end >$displayMonth</option>
                                #end
                            #end
                        </select>

                        <select name="year" id="year">
                            #foreach($lyear in $util.listYears)
                                <option value="$lyear" #if($year == $lyear) selected #end >$lyear</option>
                            #end
                        </select>

                        ##"${R}-01"
                        ##set($begin = "${R}-01")

                        ##<input type="hidden" name="month2" value=#set(${lyear}-${key}) />


                        ##ih
                        <input type="hidden" name="month2" value=${lyear}-${displayMonth} />

                        ##set($month = $lyear-$displayMonth)

                        ##<input type="hidden" name="month2" value="${lyear}-${displayMonth}" />

                        ##<input type="hidden" name="month2" value="#set(${lyear}-${key})" />

                        <input type="submit" value="&nbsp;" class="button27 btnOk hand" style="margin-right:0;"/>               

                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <span>ou</span>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>                   
                        <span><td><a href="/comptes/mon_compte.html?display=affilies">Revenir à la page de rémunération globale</a></td>



</span>
                  </p>
               </form> 
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`#set`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#set) is used to assign values to Velocity variables. To print the current value of a variable, just write the variable name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="month2" value="${lyear}-${key}" />
```

You must understand that Velocity is a **templating language**, which means that it mixes code within another markup language (usually HTML, but it can be something as simple as plain text or as complex as PDF), and after the Velocity code is executed and the variables are printed (*interpolated*), only the other markup remains. So, trying to `#set` some variables doesn't change the outcome in any way, and it certainly won't set a value for an HTML attribute, since Velocity doesn't know or care about HTML at all.